# Error in accessing JSON object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous

I have a variable **var sessions={}** in file called **'UserSessions.js'**. I am maintaining some information of each user in **sessions={}** with a unique timestamp. I have exported this variable to make it available to other files.

When I access the **sessions={}** in main file **'app.js'** everything works fine.

But when I try to access same variable from another file **'Sessiongreet.js'**, it gives error.

Here is how I access the data :

Suppose **'2017-04-07T11:55:40.162Z'** is the unique timestamp assigned only once.

In app.js:

This Works fine:

```
const UserSessions=require('./UserSessions.js');

sessionId='2017-04-07T11:55:40.162Z';

var data=UserSessions.sessions[sessionId].context;
```

In sessionGreet.js:

This gives error:

```
const UserSessions=require('./UserSessions.js');

sessionId='2017-04-07T11:55:40.162Z';

var data=UserSessions.sessions[sessionId].context;
```

I know that **UserSessions.sessions[sessionId].context** exists as it is accessible in **app.js** file before accessing it in another file.

Here is the exact error what I get :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '2017-04-07T11:55:40.162Z' of undefined
    at initSession (/media/row_hammer/sessionGreet.js:24:33)
    at Object.run (/media/row_hammer/sessionGreet.js:67:2)
    at Object.handlePostback (/media/row_hammer/sessionTemp.js:89:19)
    at runPostback (/media/row_hammer/app.js:113:15)
    at /media/row_hammer/app.js:161:3
    at Object.findOrCreateSession (/media/row_hammer/UserSessions.js:83:4)
    at Bot.bot.on (/media/row_hammer/app.js:159:15)
    at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
    at Bot.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at Bot._handleEvent (/media/row_hammer/node_modules/messenger-bot/index.js:254:10)
```

Also, In sessionGreet.js:

```
//EVEN this line shows 'undefined'
console.log(UserSessions.sessions);
```

Why am I getting this error even though flow of program is correct?

Comment: can you post here a code from UserSessions.js ? It interesting how do you export the "session" variable.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that app.js and Sessiongreet.js are in different folders.

'./UserSessions.js' means that UserSessions.js is in the same folder as the file issuing the require().

If app.js is in the same folder as UserSessions.js, but Sessiongreet.js is in different folder, this would explain your issue.

Comment: no.. 'UserSessions.js' and 'app.js' are in same folder.

Comment: btw..I found out the solution... I use global.sessions={} instead of var sessions={}. Simply made 'sessions={}' global.Its working well now.